# Why does my render output change everytime I click render image?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, fluid-simulation, motion-blur

I am using Blender v2.83.0 to render a Motion Tracked car with Smoke simulation in Blender and I cannot seem to get my render settings correct.

I am getting a problem where every time I click 'render image' I get one of four options. I either get the full scene rendered correctly, just the car, just the car but it's blacked out or the full scene rendered correctly but the smoke is stretched. Image examples can be seen below:

[image: Full Scene - Rendered Correctly]

[image: Just the Car - Missing Smoke]

[image: Just the Car - Blacked Out]

[image: Full Scene - Stretched Smoke]

All my layers are on the same view layer and I would really appreciate any suggestions. My compositing is simply a render layer into composite.

Thanks in advance,
Ethan

Answer (score 0):

Physics must be baked before rendering.

Go to Phisics settings, find Cache tab, change type to Final and press Bake All button.

[image]

Also notice, blend-file must be saved on disc.

Comment: Hey Crantisz, thanks for your incredibly quick response. Unfortunately, I have done both of these. My physics are baked and my blender file is saved. The only thing I changed during this process was I did not save my Blender Cache in the same place my Blender project was? They are on the same drive but not folder... would this make a difference??? Thanks again.

Comment: Hm. In this case, can you provide the file?

Comment: Why yes of course, here is the link to it in my Google Drive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hNgTTJFQYtj8cbd_nd74rechtOZB45Jn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just thought I'd add now, I am re-rendering my project using Blender 2.82 instead and I am having no problems so far. Have a feeling it may just be the new release not agreeing with my project?